# Does (get-item $file).GetHashCode() calculate the hash on the fly like get-filehash or used a pre-computed hash?

Tags: powershell

We're working on a PowerShell script for forensic baseline analysis which recursively iterates over the file-system recording a hierarchy of directories and files, with the filenames mapped to hashes and dump that data to JSON. Since we're interested in doing this for every file on the system, it needs to be as fast as it can be.

The ideal output for a small test directory is like:

```
{
    "\\3D Objects":  {

                     },
    "\\Contacts":  {

                   },
    "\\Desktop":  {
                      "\\that":  {
                                     "\\somedoc":  "@{textdoc.txt=C700784FAD1A992A90D71CBC1ADB0F22BF286AD6FE4C9BF42A0407BAF8F3D068}",
                                     "bruh.txt":  "E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855",
                                     "eula.lnk":  "FD068EACB3CC0C1ED2F246542426680F255614791BCD4E0EC615A4B1CEF1F0FA"
                                 },
                      "\\this":  {
                                     "\\another folder":  "@{\\kelp=; thebesometext.txt=BE47BDE1B74F38E47064C1185A1AC8261C9EEEBE9D32ACF25047F5BC4EB5BC8D}",
                                     "ok.txt":  "C5273884B90D490134E7737B29A65405CEA0F7BB786CA82C6337CEB24DE6F5ED",
                                     "sample.txt":  "766D6A6A2330070C98D2AD44C9A4345DB8C6E65BAECC82B6D2CF801126F98DF6"
                                 },
                      "192.168.176.131_Scraped_Files.zip":  "153891A4A3951D9D86C0DFC3F1D9B5FB7886EC754237B078C5657E271A8EC5FB",
                      "bruh.rar":  "BA9B9AD700B82029AEC0DAE52B06E4A09C60255D996DD5A40F7DED61D3DD2795",
                      "FileSystemtoJSON.ps1":  "2E8C2CDFD495DB137B7B46A7FDAC6040E51CD6464D5B9C84B67F179D2B7A9C2B",
                      "File_Scraper.ps1":  "7BFD3600894D39CEEB1BE921C24A3BCDB58C4CE1114D376DB908A95F2CF49FC1",
                      "FStoJson.ps1":  "FACF2C77FA004502C10066E8757D31B1A134878345965F60B80D5CC7CF2A2B44"
                  },
    "\\Documents":  {
                        "\\WindowsPowerShell":  {

                                                }
                    },
    "\\Downloads":  {
                        "winrar-x64-611.exe":  "24FC7955FADA6B9802F4E50E935EBD5654FD7382FAF641B27DD626F4B3563974"
                    },
    "\\Favorites":  {
                        "\\Links":  {

                                    },
                        "Bing.url":  "E0C0A5A360482B5C5DED8FAD5706C4C66F215F527851AD87B31380EF6060696E"
                    },
    "\\Links":  {
                    "Desktop.lnk":  "B559BF8483620D2C64B12901AAC7CAB21219F750E97FFC7FFC2808A7B5B9648D",
                    "Downloads.lnk":  "A0F8549CAB3926988971D8738CB9DE27964B6B47707674A3419DDCCA82935565"
                },
    "\\Music":  {

                },
    "\\OneDrive":  {

                   },
    "\\Pictures":  {
                       "\\Camera Roll":  {

                                         },
                       "\\Saved Pictures":  {

                                            }
                   },
    "\\Saved Games":  {

                      },
    "\\Searches":  {
                       "winrt--{S-1-5-21-321011808-3761883066-353627080-1000}-.searchconnector-ms":  "3B33937704E0EBEC50DD91E982DD4CADDC1ED0DB23864AB28A14A43910C393D0"
                   },
    "\\Videos":  {

                 }
}
```

Our original script was like this:

```
$root = [PSCustomObject]@{}

function FSSkimmer {
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$path,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][PsCustomObject]$currentobject)

$paths = gci $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname
    foreach ($file in $paths) { 
        if (!$(get-item $file | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSiscontainer)) {
            $name = get-item $file | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
            $hash = Get-FileHash $file -Algorithm SHA256 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Hash
            $currentobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $name -Value $hash
        }
        else {
            $dir_name = get-item $file | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
            $dir = [PSCustomObject]@{}
            $currentobject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "\$($dir_name)" -Value $(FSSkimmer -path $file -currentobject $dir)
        }
    }
return $currentobject
}

$null = FSSkimmer -path "C:\" -currentobject $root

ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $root
```

This is slow. Reducing the hashing algorithm from Sha-256 to something less computationally expensive does help the speed. But I noticed one alternative:

```
(get-item $file).GetHashCode()
```

Is there anything fundamentally different about this method to `get-filehash`? Is it using some pre-computed hash stored by windows? (I know file-explorer shows a hash when you pull the properties, but don't know if this hash is cached on every file write or calculated on the fly every time properties are open. I suspect for some reason this might be the same feature exposed in PS.

Comment: "A hash code is a numeric value that is used to insert and identify an object in a hash-based collection such as the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> class, the Hashtable class, or a type derived from the DictionaryBase class. The GetHashCode method provides this hash code for algorithms that need quick checks of object equality." (this is not the same as a file hash provided by `Get-FileHash` or `HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash`)

Comment: Following the previous comments, there are ways to improve your scripts runtime, in example, not using `gci` which is pretty slow, not using `add-member` and create a class instead, using a `collections.queue` instead of recursion, etc...

Comment: the result is an `int32` that is also used for hashtable indexes and other hash-oriented lookup collections. it is NOT as robust as the others that you are using ... but it _is_ enuf for "is this probably the same as that?" testing. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yeah and I can't afford that, since my use-case is forensics and a hash collision can be used by attackers to make malware have an identical hash to something benign.

Comment: @J.Todd - kool! if you need more speed ... there are ways to speed up your code. ///// [1] post/move your Question over at the code review site. ///// [2] replace `Get-ChildItem` with `robocopy`. the 2nd can give you just the full file names without changing anything. ///// [3] use a 3rd party hash util that is optimized for speed. ///// [4] build your output objects with `[PSCustomObject]` instead of `Add-Member`.

Answer (score 0):

Just check it. Create some folders, copy the same file into them and run something like this:

```
$tmp=Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\test' -Recurse
foreach ($file in $tmp) {
  Get-FileHash -Path $file.FullName -Algorithm MD5 
  Write-Host $file.GetHashCode()
  Write-Host ($file.name).GetHashCode()
}
```

You will see, that FileHash is the same, but HashCode is different in first case and the same in second. I think .GetHashCode() works with object properties (name, lenght, path, etc ) but not with the "content" of object